# How can I view live logs on a Linux server (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging

How can I view a live log on a Linux server, so that I can see new log entries instantly as they are being added?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Over the Terminal

In the most simple case:

```
tail -f /var/log/name-of-logfile-you-want-to-watch
```

The `-f` option "follows" the file and will automatically update the view as the file is being updated. For a list of possible log files, you can see [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-gnome-system-log-viewer/) or just explore them yourself.

---

#### Using a GUI log viewer

If you have GNOME as a graphical environment installed, it comes with a log viewer called `gnome-system-log`. Open it with:

```
gnome-system-log &
```

You will [find a manual here](http://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-system-log/stable/introduction.html.en).

Comment: If there are any other requirements (your question wasn't that specific), just report back.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Just one more question, what dose the `trail` function actually do?

Comment: `tail` not trail. `tail` prints the "tail" of given file :). By default last 10 lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use less if you're interested in that interface rather than tail.

`less /var/log/syslog`

and then press Shift-F to scroll to the bottom. Less will watch for more text.

Comment: Press / to search for words